# Which default encoding for Vim: utf8 or latin1?

Tags: vim, encoding, character-encoding

I'm writing text in European languages
as French, German, Italian.

All characters are compatible with latin1 encoding.

Thats why I decided to set the default encoding in vim to latin1.

Once in a while I have problems p.e. the latest ycm plugin doesn't work fine with latin1.

What default character encoding are you using in vim?
Is it a problem to convert `menu.vim` and `_vimrc` from latin1 to utf8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a question that you will see popping up on database related questions (like [utf-8 vs latin1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449336/utf-8-vs-latin1) or [when to use utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857778/when-to-use-utf-8-and-when-to-use-latin1-in-mysql). In general UTF-8 is more complete and more widely adopted. So anyone developing is more likely to support utf-8 than somethin like latin1, which I (perhaps wrongly) associate with windows platforms more than anything else.

The most common denominator today is utf-8 so I would switch to that. Converting existing documents should be no issue if you use `set fileencoding=utf8` and save. See also [this post on conversion in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310274/how-can-i-use-vim-to-convert-my-file-to-utf8).

Answer (score 2):

You asked,

> Is it a problem to convert menu.vim and _vimrc from latin1 to utf8?

It shouldn't be a problem, and FvD's answer shows how easy it can be.

But you also should not need to.

The scripts which come with Vim, shouldn't be using any fancy characters whose byte representation changes when switching from latin1 to utf-8. If any of your custom scripts rely on a specific file encoding, you can either convert them, OR, you can add a "scriptencoding whateverEncodingName" command to the top of the script, and Vim will convert and interpret it properly as it reads in the file data (the file itself remains in the old encoding).